# Is there always a g in a compact connected Lie group whose powers equidistributes in G?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, equidistribution

I'm starting to understand some basics things about equidistributed sequences and i found my self asking this question on the basis of the example of the torus and Weyl equidistribution theorem:

Given a compact(real) connected Lie group $G$, is there always an element $g \in G$ such that $\{g^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ equidistributes in $G$, with respect to the Haar-measure of $G$?

Is for example this property true for the rotation groups of Euclidean spaces $SO(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Thanks for any suggestion

Edit: the answer received in the comment gives that for trivial reason the orthogonal group never enjoys this property for n>2. So my next dumb question is: what are the other examples where there is this property, apart from products of $S^1$ a finite number of times?

Comment: I really don't know what I'm talking about here, but even on $SO(3)$ this seems dubious. $g^n$ is always rotation around the same axis as $g$. So $g^n$ cannot be very close to a non-trivial rotation around a perpendicular axis.

Comment: You're right! and a similar argument works for greater dimension: it suffices to notice that every rotation leaves invariant a 2 dimensional space. So it is trivially false.